# wrapping full width divs around a floating div

Tags: css, xhtml

I'm trying to do something with a floating div, which I thought would be simplest ever, but I seem utterly unable to achieve what I want. I want to have a fixed width floating div and have all divs around it expand horizontally as far as they can without overlapping the floating div. That is, next to the floating div they should fill the space available next to it and under the floating div they should occupy the full width of the container.

I've tried every combination of `position`, `display`, `width`, and `right` properties I could think of, but nothing gives me what I want. I should think that I need to set the `.fill` divs to `display: inline-block;` and then manage the width of them with the `width` or `right` property, but nothing that I try gives me the **available** width.

Note that I can not know beforehand which divs will be next to the floating div, as the height of all divs is variable, thus I can not set explicit widths for the `.fill` divs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:s
chemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd">
<head>
  <title>float test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body, div {
      margin: 0;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #right {
      width: 20em;
      height: 40em;
      margin: 0 0 0 1em;
      float: right;
      background-color: #88f;
      opacity: .5;
    }
    .fill {
      height: 3em;
      margin: 1em;
      background-color: #f88;
      opacity: .5;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="left">
      <div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div>
      <div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div>
      <div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div>
      <div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div><div class="fill"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `overflow: hidden;` to `.fill`

Comment: You're Welcome.. sometimes it's the extra pair of eyes `;)`